# How can I add custom classes to each view's generated row?

Tags: views, theming, 8

Is it possible by using the theme preprocessor add some classes to views generated rows?

For example: based on Drupal site about default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
[views-view-unformatted.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view-unformatted.html.twig/8.2.x):

> Available variables:
>   - **title:** The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
>  
>   - **rows:** A list of the view's row items.
>  
>   - **attributes:** The row's HTML attributes.
>  
>   - **content:** The row's content.
>   - **view:** The view object.
>   - **default_row_class:** A flag indicating whether default classes
>      should be used on rows.

I know that it's possible and we can add our desired classes to each row inside the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to understand is it possible to do the same thing for custom views like `front-page` by use of:
[function template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted__frontpage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/8.2.x) in particular
or in other [template_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x) generally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at /core/modules/views/views.theme.inc at template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted you'll see this code:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  $style = $view->style_plugin;
  $options = $style->options;

  $variables['default_row_class'] = !empty($options['default_row_class']);
  foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    $variables['rows'][$id] = [];
    $variables['rows'][$id]['content'] = $row;
    $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes'] = new Attribute();
    if ($row_class = $view->style_plugin->getRowClass($id)) {
      $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass($row_class);
    }
  }
}
```

This is how if you have set a row class in the view, it gets added.

[image]

And the resulting output:

[image]

You can copy this function to your custom module and customize it as you like.  For example, this will add the "views-row-" plus the name of your view cleaned up using the pathauto cleanstring utility:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];

  foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    // Add custom class to each row that encorporates the view id.
    $custom_row_class = \Drupal::service('pathauto.alias_cleaner')
      ->cleanString($view->id());
    $custom_row_class = 'views-row-' . $custom_row_class;
    $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass($custom_row_class);
  }
}
```

If you would like to add classes to a views rows from hook_preprocess_views_view, you can do it this way:

```
function mitsloan_global_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  if ($view->id() == 'testview') {

    $row_style_plugin = &$variables['rows'][0]['#view']->style_plugin;

    $custom_row_class = 'views-row-' . \Drupal::service('pathauto.alias_cleaner')
        ->cleanString($view->id());

    $row_style_plugin->options['row_class'] = $custom_row_class;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you greatly, This code works correctly for `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted` but it seems that not works in `hook_preprocess_views_view`.

Comment: I have added an example for hook_preprocess_views_view.

Comment: The best possible answer, I sincerely appreciate your efforts. Thanks for everything ;-)

Comment: why d7's _preprocess_views_view_unformatted hook do not have this ability? any thought..

Comment: An alternative to using pathauto is `Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier()`, although it doesn't give you as much control over the output as Pathauto.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check various [loop variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) defined by twig and use them to apply unique classes, e.g.

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {% if (loop.index == 1 ) %}
        {% set is_active = 'is-active' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set is_active = '' %}
    {% endif %}
    <li class="{{ is_active }} counter{{ loop.index }}">
        {{ row.content }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**loop.index**  The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)

**loop.index0** The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

**loop.revindex**   The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1 indexed)

**loop.revindex0**  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0 indexed)

**loop.first**  True if first iteration

**loop.last**   True if last iteration

**loop.length** The number of items in the sequence

**loop.parent** The parent context

Comment: Great to know that twig is natively tracking the loop count.

Comment: Minimal code solution!

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I think this will work:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $id = $view->storage->id();

  if ($id == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'custom-class-name';
  }
}
```

**Note** the `$view->current_display` is the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).

- You can remove the `&& $view->current_display == 'block_1'` part if
  you don't want it to be this specific.
- You can remove the if statement if you want to affect ALL views.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you greatly, This code works correctly for Drupal 8, but adds classes to the parent item, not to the each child rows.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani I find that very surprising considering the twig says `- attributes: The row's HTML attributes.`

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be conditional or just a view added to each row? You can do that in the UI. The front page rows can have a class added to them by doing to /admin/structure/views/view/frontpage and clicking on "settings" next to "unformatted list". This has a row class field which might be what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, But I want to do this work programmatically and just into the theme layer.